# regex match string but not another

Tags: c#, regex

I have the two following strings

```
/signon/default.wl?rs=WLW11.10&vr=2.0&fn=_top
/signon/default.wl?fn=%5Ftop&newdoor=true&rs=WLW11%2E10&vr=2%2
```

I would like to match all the strings except the ones that do not contain newdoor

so far i have the following regex

> /signon/default.wl\?(?=[\w]*)(?!newdoor)

but it matches all strings.
can anyone point out what im doing wrong.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: .net, but im currently testing on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this `/signon/default.wl\?(?!.*newdoor).*`

It asserts using negative lookahead that there is no occurrence of `newdoor`  in the input string. Code will look like this

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"/signon/default.wl\?(?!.*newdoor).*", 
               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Comment: both suggestions, work but I'm going with this version as I just need to test the string rather then get the content.

Comment: +1, but be aware that you could have used `Regex.IsMatch()` to a boolean directly.  Also, the `Multiline` option isn't doing anything useful in this case.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for pointing out. Removed the `Multiline` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
/signon/default.wl\?(?=[\w]*)(?!newdoor)
```

Both `(?=)` and `(?!)` are zero-width assertions that don't consume any input. Try:

```
/signon/default.wl\?(.(?!newdoor))*$
```

Comment: -1. In the first regex, `(?=[\w]*)` will always succeed because `[\w]*` can match zero characters; and `(?!newdoor)` is applied only once, immediately after the `?`.  The second regex incorrectly matches `/signon/default.wl?newdoor` because the dot consumes the `n` in `newdoor` before the lookahead can stop it.  It's a valid technique, but you're supposed to place the dot *after* the lookahead: `(?:(?!newdoor).)*`.  (I see that error a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

why not use something like:

```
subjectString.contains("newdoor");
```